# Can I set up this recursion in a smarter way to avoid calls to an expensive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

Suppose I have a Matrix class `Matrix`, and a recursive function that does some computation using it. In particular, `heavy_computation` is a really expensive function and I'd like to avoid calling it whenever possible.

```
bool heavy_computation(const Matrix& m)
{
    // Expensive stuff ...
}
```

The `do_things` function is a top level function the user calls to kick off recursion.

```
void do_things(const Matrix& m, std::vector<int>& collection)
{
    std::vector<int> expensive_result;

    if(!heavy_computation(m, expensive_result))
    {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "New result = { ";
    for(int i : expensive_result)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "}\n";

    for(int i : expensive_result)
    {
        collection.emplace_back(i);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        explore(m, j, expensive_result, collection);
    }
}
```

The top level function delegates work to the following `explore` function.

```
void explore(
    const Matrix& m,
    int j,
    const std::vector<int>& expensive_result,
    std::vector<int>& collection)
{
    std::cout << "j = " << j << "\n";

    // Compute something based on expensive_result.
    Matrix new_matrix = ...;

    std::vector<int> new_expensive_result;
    heavy_computation(new_matrix , new_expensive_result);

    if (!new_expensive_result.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "New result = { ";
        for (int i : new_expensive_result)
            std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << "}\n";

        for (int i : new_expensive_result)
        {
            collection.emplace_back(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (!new_expensive_result.empty())
        {
            explore(new_matrix, i, expensive_result, collection);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have stared at the structure of the recursion for too long; it could most probably be organized in a more clever way to avoid unnecessary calls to `heavy_computation`. For example, consider the following output the program gives:

```
New result = { 9 7 8 }
j = 0
New result = { 5 0 6 }
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
New result = { 3 1 0 }
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
j = 1                     <--- Oh no, { 5 0 6 } will be recomputed again?!
New result = { 5 0 6 }
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
New result = { 3 1 0 }
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
j = 2
New result = { 5 0 6 }
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
```

If I understand correctly, the problem here is that as `explore` returns, `heavy_computation` can be called again (and of course it'll return the same answer again as it's deterministic). Basically, a branch of `explore` will be killed if `heavy_computation` gives false, otherwise the recursion advances deeper. Is there a way to set up `do_things` and `explore` so that unnecessary calls to the expensive function are avoided?

When compared to the output, I guess 3 calls to the expensive function should suffice as we don't have any more unique answers.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code structure in detail, but would [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) be appropriate here?

Comment: If that is the output from your code, it means that `heavy_computation` is stateful (the first two calls get the same input, but produce different output). So, either you cannot optimize this without looking at what that function does, or you wasted my time by not posting your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are some things you can improve in the code to make it easier to read and maintain. Why are you passing `j` to the `explore` function? You only use it for printing, so just do that before calling the function.

Second, this

```
for (int i : new_expensive_result)
{
    collection.emplace_back(i);
}
```

is the same (except slower) as

```
collection.insert(collection.end(),
    new_expensive_result.begin(), new_expensive_result.end());
```

Third, there is a lot of code duplication between your two functions. You should have removed that before posting your code here.

Solving your problem is quite straightforward, really. First, split the `explore` function into two functions: one containing the code up to and including the call to `heavy_computation`, and one for the rest. The recursive call will now consist of two calls, where you have to pass some output of the first function to the second. Something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    if (!new_expensive_result.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "j = " << i << "\n";

        Matrix matrix_result;
        std::vector<int> vector_result;
        explore1(new_matrix, expensive_result, matrix_result, vector_result);
        explore2(new_matrix, expensive_result, matrix_result, vector_result, collection);
    }
}
```

Now it is obvious that you can lift the call to `explore1` (which calls `heavy_computation`) out of the loop.